# Conversion rate in volume of freshly picked beans as opposed to dried beans

Tags: beans

I wish to use fresh beans instead of dried ones.For a kg of dried beans as per the recipe how much of fresh beans should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "fresh beans"? Beans are eaten either green or ripe, and ripe beans are already dry before picking. If your recipe specifies ripe dry beans, you cannot substitute green beans.

Answer (score 2):

if by "fresh" you mean as in cooked canned beans, the general rule of thumb is one part dried beans equals three parts cooked beans, so you should be looking to use 3kg of canned beans. This is, of course, after draining.

Comment: If the question is about canned beans, it is a duplicate. But I have a hard time imagining anybody using "fresh" as a synonym for "canned"